# MSSQL View to MS Access 2016 Linked Table Real not importing as double

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

```
SELECT NumChan, 
        CntChanUsed, 
        ([CntChanUsed]/([NumChan]*1.0))*100 AS PcntChanUsed
 FROM qryIOAllocVisualisationChanCount
```

I have a field, PcntChanUsed, which has data stored as a real in MSSQL Server and when I import to Access it imports as a Number with a Field Size of Long Integer. This means that my value is not rounded correctly and the data is incorrect.

How do I get around this?

Comment: What are the data types of `CntChanUsed` and `NumChan` ?

Comment: They are both smallint